# Split each string in array by semiclons

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have an array-like

```
[
    'email1@provider.com;email2@provider.com',
    'email3@provider.com',
    'email4@provider.com;email5@provider.com;email6@provider.com'
]
```

Which is the best way to map and split every semicolon on a string in order to form an array with each email separated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in a modern browser or environment, [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)  is really nice for splitting each item and flattening into an array.

```js
const l= [
    'email1@provider.com;email2@provider.com',
    'email3@provider.com',
    'email4@provider.com;email5@provider.com;email6@provider.com'
]

const res = l.flatMap(s => s.split(';'))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const original = [
    'email1@provider.com;email2@provider.com',
    'email3@provider.com',
    'email4@provider.com;email5@provider.com;email6@provider.com'
];

const result = original.reduce((res, str) => {
  return res.concat(str.split(';'));
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can try my way:

```js
const arr = [
  "email1@provider.com;email2@provider.com",
  "email3@provider.com",
  "email4@provider.com;email5@provider.com;email6@provider.com",
];

const newArr = arr.join(";").split(";");

console.log(newArr);
```